# Select data within current week and a certain timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, truncate

i faced a challenge of a SQL-Selection which should provide Date from the current week AND the period of time between 05:00 and 22:00. (So from this weeks Monday-Sunday the data between 5:00 and 22:00)

I searched for other questions in that direction and although i found similar ones, i didn't solved my challenge so far.

```
SELECT general_power
FROM t_power
WHERE date_trunc('week', p_date_time) = date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
AND date_trunc('hour', p_date_time) BETWEEN 'week? 05:00:00' AND 'week? 22:00:00'
```

p_date_time is a "Timestamp" Column which contains a huge amount of data for every minute of the day.

The "week?" in the last line is the problem. With this i tried to find something like a Wildcard for the week (if something like that exists). But i'm also happy for other solutions as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select general_power
from t_power
where
    date_trunc('week', p_date_time) = date_trunc('week', current_timestamp) 
    and
    p_date_time::time between '05:00:00' and '22:00:00'
```

`between` means time >= '05:00:00' and time <= '22:00:00'

Comment: thanks for the answer. its really helpful. but with the change to 22 o clock, data like 22:00:01 will also delieverd because the hours still fits :)

Comment: @Kyrill Ok. I just guessed by your query (`22:00:00`) that you only wanted time < `22:00:00`. Updated

Comment: yes, i want data from 05:00:00 to 22:00:00 (include the 22:00:00)
but with the solution, i also get 22:00:01 because the hour is still 22 :) i just made a limit test with my database

Comment: @Kyrill Ahhh... Now i get it. Updated.